# Issues with tbb parallel_reduce performance with blaze::StaticMatrix

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, shared-memory, tbb

I am planning to speed-up my fluid-dynamics solver on shared-memory machines (possibly with GPU offload in far future) and am testing tbb performance. So, I cooked up a simple example which resembles actual computations:

```cpp
#define BLAZE_USE_SHARED_MEMORY_PARALLELIZATION 0
#include <chrono>
#include <limits>
#include <blaze/math/StaticMatrix.h>
#include <blaze/math/StaticVector.h>

#include <vector>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include "oneapi/tbb/concurrent_vector.h"
#include "oneapi/tbb/parallel_reduce.h"
#include "oneapi/tbb/global_control.h"

constexpr int N=12, M=12;
using matrix = blaze::StaticMatrix<double, N, M, blaze::rowMajor, blaze::aligned, blaze::padded>;

double f(const matrix &up) {
  //pointless but expensive computations
  double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
  for (auto i = 0ul; i < up.columns(); ++i){
    max = std::max(max, blaze::evaluate( blaze::max(blaze::sin(blaze::asin(blaze::column(up, i))))));
  }
  return max;
};

int main() {
  int nr_threads = 20;
  oneapi::tbb::global_control global_limit(oneapi::tbb::global_control::max_allowed_parallelism,
                       nr_threads);
  
  std::size_t nr_elems = 5e6;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
  std::vector<matrix> v1;
  v1.reserve(nr_elems);
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < nr_elems; ++i){
    matrix u;
    u = std::sin(-3 + i * 6. /nr_elems);
    v1.push_back(u);
  }
  
  start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
  for(const auto &u : v1){
    max = blaze::max(f(u), max);
  }
  end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<double> single_time = end - start;

  oneapi::tbb::concurrent_vector<matrix> tbb_v(oneapi::tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<matrix>{});
  tbb_v.reserve(nr_elems);
  for(const auto &u : v1){
    tbb_v.push_back(u);
  }

  int repeats = 20;
  // computing the maximum of f(u) where u is in v1
  std::chrono::duration<double> parallel_reduce_time(0.0);
  for(int i =0; i < repeats; i++){
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    max = oneapi::tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0,nr_elems, 1000)
                       , min,
                       [&](const auto &r, double init) {
                     for (auto i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) {
                       init =std::max(init, f(tbb_v[i]));
                     }
                     return init;
                       },
                       [](double max1, double max2) {
                     return std::max(max1, max2);
                       }, oneapi::tbb::simple_partitioner{});
    end  = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    parallel_reduce_time += (end - start);
  }
  fmt::print("Parallel_reduce Time {}\n", parallel_reduce_time.count() / repeats);
  fmt::print("Single for Time {}\n", single_time.count());
  fmt::print("Speedup: {}\n", single_time.count() / parallel_reduce_time.count() * repeats);
  fmt::print("Result: {}\n", max);
  
  return 0;
}
```

but I don't get any near expected performance, currently on a dell precision 5570 I obtain a speedup of around 7 of 20 available processes. I ran Vtune but it doesn't show any spin time of the threads, so they all seem busy. Furthermore, I checked the examples from the oneTBB github (parallel_reduce/prime) to see if my machine maybe just sucks, but this gives around 17x speedup that is absolutely acceptable. Do you have any hint, maybe I am doing something very wrong?

PS: the plan is to run the parallelised code on some NUMA machines with 4x AMD Epyc and Nvidia A100. Do you think tbb is a cool choice of library for that?

Comment: Could you please let us know whether you observe similar performance issue on Intel machines